# Spring Boot + ajax:Method not allowed

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring

При попытке отправить POST запрос возникает ошибка 405. Использую Spring Security поэтому в мете использую csrf.

html:

```
<meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

jQuery:

```
let formData = {'flag': false}
setLike("/ideas/setLike-" + id, formData, id)

function setLike(url, formData, id){
    $.ajax ({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (fragment) {
            $("#idea-" + id).html($('#idea-' + id, fragment).html())
        }
    });
}

$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    let token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    let header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
});
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping("/setLike-{idea}")
public String setLike(@PathVariable Idea idea, Model model, Principal principal, 
@RequestParam boolean flag){
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(principal.getName());

    if (flag) ideaService.addLike(user, idea);
    else ideaService.remLike(user, idea);

    ideaRepository.save(idea);
    ideaRepository.flush();

    return "redirect:";
}
```

Главное - такое только на проде, на локальном хосте всё окей...

Comment: проверьте правильность URL- адреса во сновном 405 может вылететь именно поетому

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина ошибки заключалась в следующем: После отправки POST запроса с помощью ajax нужный метод исполнялся, но возвращал редирект на метод GET.

Исправил, изменив возвращаемое значение:

```
@PostMapping("/setLike-{idea}")
public String setLike(@PathVariable Idea idea, Model model, Principal 
principal,@RequestParam boolean flag){
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(principal.getName());

    if (flag) ideaService.addLike(user, idea);
    else ideaService.remLike(user, idea);

    ideaRepository.save(idea);
    ideaRepository.flush();

    return "ideas"; // Изменил данную строчку, теперь нет редиректа
}
```